# c++. function pointer to template function produces unresolved overloaded function type error

Tags: c++, templates

I need to make a class method take a template function as a pointer to function parameter, and then call it.

But I am running into

```
ThreadPool.hh:55:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘ThreadPoolElem<int>::start(<unresolved overloaded function type>, ThreadPoolElem<int>*)’
```

Samples and explanation of my code are :

I have a main module ThreadPool, which have a vector of ThreadPoolElem. As you may have guessed ThreadPoolElem are an encapsulation of Threads and ThreadPool plays the thread pool manager role. From ThreadPool I need to iterate the threadPoolElem vector. For each element in the vector I need to call its 'start' member function which take 2 argumens (the first one being a pointer to function). In the 'start' member function of The ThreadPoolElem class it uses the first argument as the callback for the third pthread_create c library function.

my threadpool file goest like this :

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadPool
{
 Mutex _mutex;
 CondVar _condVar;
 SafeQueue<T> _tasks;
 std::vector<ThreadPoolElem<T> > _threadVector;
 /* .... */
   void run(void)
 {
 for (typename std::vector<ThreadPoolElem<T> >::iterator it =    this>_threadVector.begin();
     it != this->_threadVector.end();
     ++it)
  {
    it->start(run_tramp, &(*it));
  }
 }
```

My ThreadPoolElem file goes like this:

```
template <typename T>
 class ThreadPoolElem : public ThreadT<T>
 {
 SafeQueue<T> *_tasks;
 CondVar *_condVar;
 Mutex *_mutex;

 public:
 ThreadPoolElem(void) {}
  void init(SafeQueue<T> *queue, CondVar *condVar, Mutex *mutex){
  this->_mutex = mutex;
  this->_condVar = condVar;
  this->_tasks = queue;
   }
  void run(void){
  while (true)
   {
    this->_mutex.lock();
    if (this->_tasks.empty())
      {
        this->_condVar->wait();
        this->_mutex->unlock();
      }
    else
      {
        int value;

        this->_tasks->tryPop(&value);
        std::cout << "consuming value" << std::endl;
        if (!this->_tasks->empty())
          {
            this->_mutex->unlock();
            this->_condVar->signal();
          }
        else
          this->_mutex->unlock();
      }
      }
    }

   };
```

This is c like function (trampoline function) i need to take as a ptr to function parameter

```
  template <typename T>
  void    *run_tramp(void *data)
  {
   reinterpret_cast<ThreadPoolElem<T> *>(data)->run();
   return NULL;
  }
```

And the final relevant file is :

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadT
{
 public:
 typedef enum
 {
  NOT_YET_STARTED,
  RUNNING,
  DEAD,
  }thread_status;

  private:
  thread_status status_;
   pthread_t     thread_;

  public:

/* .... */
   void start(void *(*ptr)(void *), void* data){
  this->status_ = RUNNING;
   if (pthread_create(&this->thread_, NULL, ptr, data) != 0)
   throw (SystemError("pthread_create"));
   }
    /* ...... */
};
```

Comment: There's no such method (`start()`) declared in `ThreadPoolElem`, but only in  `ThreadT` class?

Comment: exact only in `ThreadPoolElem` class. If i take all the templating in the `run_tramp` function, it compiles with no problem

Comment: `ThreadPoolElem` inherits from `ThreadT`, this is why no problem is coming up from this. Sorry if I haven't made myself clear in my post :/

Comment: The function pointer you're using for your _'trampoline function'_ isn't bound to a templated instance. I'm not sure, but may be `it->start(run_tramp<T>, &(*it));` helps.

Comment: Thank you man ! it works ! i have been stuck for hours ! :D

Comment: You're welcome. I made it an answer!

Comment: And I also would love to get an upvote and accept for my efforts ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using a templated function instantiation when you pass the pointer to your *'trampoline function'* to the `ThreadT<T>::start()` method, you'll need to specify for which `T` it should be instantiated:

```
it->start(run_tramp<T>, &(*it));
                // ^^^
```